# Filter runs in infinite redirect loop

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, redirect-loop

I am making a Student Management System in which i have three users. 
Admin, Student and Super admins. 
I am handling authorization via Filter. When users login it redirect it according to his role, e.g if user is student redirect user to student page.
But problem is with SuperAdmin
in FilterBean

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Sikandar
 */
public class FilterBean implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        //HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("userName");
        String role = (String) session.getAttribute("role");
        System.out.println("role in Filter out side condition " +role);
        String url = req.getRequestURI();
        if (session == null || userName == null) {
            System.out.println("The role is if session == null "+role);
            if (url.indexOf("admin.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("student.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("superadmin.xhtml") >= 0) {
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/login.xhtml");
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        } else {

            if(role.equals("admin") && (url.indexOf("login.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("superadmin.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("student.xhtml") >= 0)) {
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/admin.xhtml");
            } else if (role.equals("super") && (url.indexOf("login.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("student.xhtml") >=0)) {
                System.out.println("role == super "+url.indexOf("admin.xhtml"));
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/superadmin.xhtml");
            } else if (role.equals("student") && (url.indexOf("login.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("admin.xhtml") >=0 || url.indexOf("superadmin.xhtml") >= 0)) {
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/student.xhtml");
            } 
            else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}

else if (role.equals("super") && (url.indexOf("login.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("student.xhtml") >=0)) {
                System.out.println("role == super "+url.indexOf("admin.xhtml"));
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/superadmin.xhtml");
```

if i put `url.indexOf("superadmin.xhtml");` in this condition it says there is more redirection in page.

Comment: why do you need to check for all pages and always redirect to the same page? Your code if it works will redirect the super admin always to the super admin page no matter that he requested student.xhtml or login.xhtml

Comment: The proper way would be to handle the role in the login page and when the user types username/password to redirect to the proper result. After that make a filter that only checks if the user is logged in and redirects him to the login page if he isn't.

Answer (score 0):

`url.indexOf("superadmin.xhtml");` and `url.indexOf("admin.xhtml");`

Both contains **admin.xhtml** as suffix this may a issue try to rename **superadmin.xhtml** to **adminsuper.xhtml**